# How to design a big class header file in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a big C++ class, which includes 5 other classes inside, and some of them have other classes inside. The total length of a header (`.h`) file is very big and it is unreadable. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
// Foo.h file
#ifndef __INCLUDE_FOO_H
#define __INCLUDE_FOO_H
namespace foo {
class Foo {
public:
  #include "foo/Bar.h"
  void f() { /* something here */ }
};
}
#endif
```

This is the sub-class:

```
// Foo/Bar.h file
class Bar {
}
```

What do you think? Is it a proper approach or I'm re-inventing a wheel?

Comment: Note that creating names like __INCLUDE_FOO_H are is illegal in your own code. and there isn't normally really a need for complicated class nesting.

Comment: "I have a big C++ class, which includes 5 other classes inside, and some of them have other classes inside."  ...  *Why?* ...

Comment: I need to have inner classes because they are related only to the parent class and have no meaning outside of it. For example, it's a container and items inside it.

Comment: They can stil be outside of the class, have private constructors and be `friend` with the classes that needs them. And in the case you ever need another class to instanciate one of those, you'll just have to add it to the `friend` list.

Comment: If a class is that big, it probably don't follows the **single responsability principle** (SRP). If that class is both include by many files and is including a lot of other classes, then it can cause many recompilation if any of those classes are not very stable. In such case, you should really consider the pimpl idiom...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making the inner classes inner classes, you're better off leaving them on their own, eventually in their own namespace:

```
// in file foo/bar.h
namespace foo_detail
{
    class Bar
    {
    };
};

// in file foo.h
#include "foo/bar.h"

class Foo
{
private:
    foo_detail::Bar  theBar;
};
```

This way your `Foo` class definition is not overly complicated, your definition files are small (and easy to skim over), you do not include things in your Foo class definition (respecting the principle of least surprise - or decreasing the number of WTF/LOC as they say) and when you look at the definition for Bar, you can clearly see it's an implementation details for foo (by the namespace name if nothing else).

Namespaces are good. Trust the namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

I would not go for the #include directive inside the class declaration. I tend to group them in one place at the beginning of the file. Furthermore, since you're using namespace, the file Bar.h would have a different meaning would it be included somewhere else in your code.

Concerning the class in class in class approach I know that this can be useful on occasion, but can't you simply just create separate class and then use instances/references/pointers of these classes wherever needed?

and my last point is, if you've got huge header, you can always define body methods in separate files (i.e. Foo.h only contains declarations, all the code goes to Foo.c). It make the compiling of your software a little bit more complex, but makes the code more readable.

Comment: "you can always define body methods in separate files" - you _definitely_ *should*.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `PIMPL`, and move all private fields to a private related class, eg.:

```
// foo.h

class FooPrivate; /* Forward declaration */

class Foo {
    public: /* Public fields, if any */

    Foo ();  /* c-tor */
    ~Foo (); /* d-tor */

    /* Public methods */
    int how_old_is_frisky (); /* Sample method declaration */

    private: /* No private fields */
        FooPrivate *priv;
}

// foo.cpp

// may be a struct, it's plain ol' data container
class FooPrivate {
    public: 
        /* Any data private to Foo. As FooPrivate
           class is declared in .cpp file, it
           will be accessible only from this file */
        Bar bar;
        Cat frisky;
        Dog goggie;        
}

/* Constructor - remember to allocate private data */
Foo::Foo ()
{
    priv = new FooPrivate;
}

/* Destructor, remember to deallocate private data */
Foo::~Foo ()
{
    delete priv;
}

/* Sample method definition */
int Foo::how_old_is_frisky ()
{
    return priv->frisky.get_age ();
}
```

This way:

1. Your header is a lot shorter
2. Your private data is really private
3. As a consequence of 2, if you change *implementation* of your class, you do not have to recompile every source file that uses merely *interface* of it.

Moreover, as shown in example, put method definitions (i.e. method bodies) in source (`.cpp`) files. This way they will be compiled only once. If you put them in header, they will be compiled every time header is compiled.

--- EDIT ---

The point of 2 and 3 is not to hide data members from malicious viewers' eyes. There is a "feature" in C++ that makes private members part of class *interface*. Ideally, private members should be part of *implementation* so users of class *interface* should not be affected in changes in *implementation*. Unfortunately, it's not the case in C++. When you change private members (ie. add new member), you change whole class *interface*, so users of your interface (i.e. all files that include your header file) have to be recompiled.

However, when you use `pointer-to-implementation` pattern, the only private member is one pointer, so only changes done to public members trigger recompilation of client code (unless you, of course, change `priv` pointer). To see real life examples, take look at Qt library, which uses PIMPL pattern extensively.

Comment: I think this makes the code much more complex (`*priv->bar` instead of `bar`) for a very little gain. Whats the point of hiding private members ? If someone tries to hack your class implementation and does undocumented things, it is his own problem anyway.

Comment: But I can easily do `FooPrivate f = new FooPrivate` in global scope. And this construct will have no meaning, but will be C++ valid

Comment: @Vincenzo you can simply forward declare the class in the private part of Foo, and declare it as class Foo::FooPrivate in your cpp to avoid that problem

Comment: @ereOn this idiom is not as much intended to hide stuff from the user of your class, but to reduce compile dependencies. Reducing compile times and (possibly) enhancing encapsulation.

Comment: @Pieter, could you please give an example? How can I forward declare the class in the private part of Foo??

Comment: @Pieter: sorry, I was editing my answer at the same time, and it seems that I have overwritten your edit.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is really consider whether or not you need all those nested classes, or could they be broken up into separate classes?

If you really do need them then what you have will work, but in all honesty, I would just put them in one big file. If you split up files like that, you're going to confuse people, who will think that those inner classes are at namespace scope when they see their header files.

Comment: +1 for the *principle of least surprise*: don´t do fancy things that will be unexpected by readers.